# GTM Registering click without changing page

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have setup DFP to return a list of Custom Creatives.  Each of these creavtives contains the following HTML:

```
<a href='%%CLICK_URL_UNESC%%' class='drop-down-ad'>Ad Link Text</a>
```

When these creatives are rendered to the page I have some JavaScript that finds all the anchor tags containing the class `drop-down-ad` and grabs the src attribute and stops the page from changing when clicked and loads content in via ajax.  I do not want the page to change but I would like to still tell DFP that the user click the link.  I am not sure if this functionality is supported by DFP?

Is making a request to the generated `CLICK_URL_UNESC` using ajax supported by DFP?  Or is this not a thing I should be doing.

Hopefully I have explained what I am trying to do ok.  Let me know if you have any questions.